# java error 104 Uncaught:illegalArgumentException

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I am trying to set a background on my home page. For that, I have written the following in the constructor

```
public MyScreen()
{

    setTitle("Hello AADi WELCOME TO AYANSYS ");

    background = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("CVMS.jpg");

    VerticalFieldManager vfm = new VerticalFieldManager(USE_ALL_HEIGHT | USE_ALL_WIDTH | VerticalFieldManager.NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL);   

    vfm.setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createBitmapBackground(Bitmap.getBitmapResource("CVMS.jpg"),Background.POSITION_X_LEFT,Background.POSITION_Y_TOP,Background.REPEAT_SCALE_TO_FIT);

    add(vfm);


}
```

Then am getting

> java error 104 Uncaught:IllegalArgumentException

Can any one please help me to solve this

Comment: We need more context to fix this. Which line is 104? Where's the rest of the code?

Comment: just now i changed one parameter in setBackground i.e is from Background.REPEAT_SCALE_TO_FIT to REPEAT_INHERIT .. now am able to get the out put but the image is repeating .. how to solve that please tell me

Comment: Please provide the full stacktrace at least, otherwise we have no idea what the original error is..

Comment: catch Throwable and debug where it is getting thrown.

Comment: Debug and make sure you aren't getting `null` back for anything.

Comment: @PeterLiljenberg. 104 is the error code, not line number.

Answer (score 0):

this exception occured when you call a method with wrong arguments, this error may type of argument.
IllegalArgumentException java doc says:

```
Thrown to indicate that a method has been passed an illegal or 
 inappropriate argument.
```

This toturial may help you: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=5
This class is unchecked exception beacuse it extend RuntimeException.
Note: for better help, you have to send more description, please explain complete your program.

Comment: public final class MyScreen extends MainScreen
 {

Comment: We don't see any MyScreen or MainScreen class !!! Do you want your problem solved without any more explanation !!! When you don't send any exception stack trace or complete your program, this forum don't help you.